# complex grep show file name and lines below last match

Tags: bash, grep

I have a shell command to grep backward the match of `"___"`, and I need a way to view +two lines below this match, as well as append the file name to the start of the grep output.

```
for f in $(find . -name "*.log"); do tac $f | grep "___" | head -n 1; done
```

I have tried adding `-A 2` but that does not return lines below what is returned, and I tried adding `file /dev/null` after grep to get it to print file name but I get an error

```
for f in $(find . -name "*.log"); do tac $f | grep "___" file /dev/null | head
 -n 1; done
grep: file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: provide sample input and exprcted output

Comment: You've made your requirements (and so the resulting code) much harder to understand and more complicated than they should be by saying you want to `grep backward the match of "___", and I need a way to view +two lines below this match` when it seems like all you REALLY want is to find every `__` and the 2 lines before or after it (I really can't tell which). Once you [edit] your question to provide the [mcve] @anubhava requested we can help you do what you want the simple way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding -A 2 to grep wouldn't work because you're piping it to `head -n 1`.

Since you only want a single match you can add `-m 1` to tell grep to stop after 1 match instead of piping into `head -n 1`

Since you've reversed the file you may want to use -B 2 (-B for before rather than -A for after).
After matching you may want to reverse again with `tac` so the match resembles the actual file contents.

As for adding the file name: you already have it in `$f`, just `echo` it.

All together something like:
`for f in $(find . -name "*.log"); do echo "${f}:"; tac ${f} | grep -m 1 -A  2 "___" | tac; done`

When you added `file /dev/null` to grep you're giving it more parameters to search which is why you got an error that `file` wasn't found because you don't have a file named `file` in your path. I believe this trick won't work when you're piping input into grep because providing files to grep will cause grep to ignore the piped input.